# How to assign a class variable "dynamically" in Python?

Tags: python, class, object, variables

I have the following code :

```
class Potion(object):
    def __init__(self,name,var,varamount):
        self.name=name
        self.var=var
        self.varamount=varamount

class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items={}
    def use_potion(self,potion):
        potion.var+=potion.varamount
        print("Used a ",potion.name," !")

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=100
        self.mana=100
        self.stamina=100

inventory=Inventory()
player=Player()
healthpotion=Potion("Health potion",player.health,50)
inventory.use_potion(healthpotion)
```

Here, my health potion is supposed to add 50 to the variable `player.health`.
But `player.health` remains unchanged, only `healthpotion.var` is changed.
Assuming I want different types of potions (stamina, mana, health), how can I dynamically assign `player.health`, `player.stamina` and `player.mana` to `potion.var` ?

Comment: Just tested it, upon `print(healthpotion.var)` it prints `150` so it is working. I'd suggest you test and come back with the exact question you had in mind.

Comment: It's probably worth reading this as a starting point: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Comment: My bad, updated the question. Should be more clear now.

Comment: By `potion.var+=potion.varamount`, you mean `setattr(player, potion.var, getattr(player, potion.var) + potion.varamount)` where `potion.var == "health"`?

Comment: You should go through a tutorial, focusing on how Python expressions are used and evaluated. Hint: `player.health` is evaluated to `100` when you send it to the `Potion` constructor. It doesn't persist as a pointer or reference to that variable.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this does not work is that you have passed the argument player.health to the Potion, this is the same as to write:

```
Potion("Health potion",100,50)
```

Comment: Then how can I assign the variable player.health, not its value ?

Comment: You should either pass the object "player" itself and set player.health in the function or implement this differently

Answer (score 0):

You need to send created instance of `Player`, not just value of their attribute:

```
class Potion(object):
    def __init__(self,name,var,varamount):
        self.name=name
        self.var=var
        self.varamount=varamount

class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items={}
    def use_potion(self,potion):
        # Your potion.var contains Player instance. Access players health.
        potion.var.health += potion.varamount
        print("Used a ",potion.name," !")

class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=100
        self.mana=100
        self.stamina=100

inventory=Inventory()
player=Player()
healthpotion=Potion("Health potion",player,50) # Send player instance.
print(player.health) # 100
inventory.use_potion(healthpotion)
print(player.health) # 150
```

Comment: That's a solution, but it only works for one type of potion : health. How can I do this with every potion type ?

Comment: You can add if else statements to your `use_potion` method. For example, `if potion.name == "Health potion": potion.var.health += potion.varamount`. For some negative potion, just subtract.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Potion():
    def __init__(self,name,var,varamount):
        self.name=name
        self.var=var
        self.varamount=varamount

class Inventory():
    def __init__(self):
        self.items={}

    def add_item(self, item):
        if item in self.items.keys():
            self.items[item] += 1
        else:
            self.items[item] = 1
        print ('Added a {} potion!'.format(item.name)

    def remove_item(self, item):
        if item in self.items.keys():
            self.items[item] -= 1
            return True
        else:
            print ('No such {} exists!'.format(item.name))
            return False


class Player():
    def __init__(self):
        self.health=100
        self.mana=100
        self.stamina=100
        self.inventory = Inventory()

    def use_item(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, Potion):
            if self.inventory.remove_item(item):
                if item.var == 'health':
                    self.health += item.varamount
                    print ('Used a {0} and healed {1}!'.format(item.name, item.varamount))

player=Player()
healthpotion=Potion("Health potion", 'health', 50)
player.use_item(healthpotion)
player.inventory.add_item(healthpotion)
player.use_item(healthpotion)

#No such Health potion exists!
#Added a health potion!
#Used a Health potion and healed 50!
```

You need to think through the way your objects work first.

Does the inventory use the potion, or does the player use the potion?

In the code I provided, I made Player class have its own inventory. And then Player can use potion that was added into its own inventory.

Comment: I find this a weird solution... `Player` knows way too much: It can iterate over `Inventory` items (a behaviour that should be encapsulated in `Inventory`, and can differentiate different `Items` (which should be encapsulated in `Item`).

Comment: @NilsWerner It all depends on how the designer wishes to classify and assign functionality to the objects. In my example, I choose to make `Player` have an `Inventory`, because I am aware that other object classes, like `Shop`, `Army`, `Monster`, `Bank` can have `Inventory`. But not all of them will have `health`, so they might have different `use_item` functionalities. For example, a health potion might harm a `Monster` which is a demon etc

Comment: You must see that it will make `Player` incredibly complex, if it needs to know about all other classes and how to interact with them, though...

Comment: There's no right or wrong answer really. Like I said, its all about the design.

Comment: You should read up on the [SOLID principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Answer (score 0):

You using objects.  Objects 'know' things - the values of their attibutes - and objects can send messages to each other  - by calling their methods.

In this case:

- `Player` knows their health.
- `Potion` knows how much it can increase health by
- `Inventory` knows whether or not the it has a potion.
- `Player` should have an inventory
- `Player` can choose to use items in its inventory
- `Inventory` keeps track of whether an item has been used

Based on these facts, we know which methods and attributes our classes need.

Potion needs to know how many health points it can restore

```
class Potion(object):

    def __init__(self,name, varamount):
        self.name=name
        self.varamount=varamount
```

Inventory needs to be able to keep track of its contents.

```
class Inventory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items={}

    def add_potion(self, potion):
        self.items['potion'] = potion

    def get_potion(self):
         return self.items.get('potion')

    def remove_potion(self):
        self.items.pop('potion', None)
```

Player needs to be able to track its health, and use potions.

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self, inventory):
        self.health=100
        self.mana=100
        self.stamina=100
        self.inventory = inventory

    def use_potion(self):
        potion = self.inventory.get_potion()
        if potion:
            self.health += potion.varamount
            self.inventory.remove_potion()
        print("Used a ",potion.name," !")

inventory=Inventory()

healthpotion=Potion("Health potion", 50)
inventory.add_potion(healthpotion)

player=Player(inventory)
player.use_potion()
```